# how to insert in to excel and save as excel in web server folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, webserver

I have an excel template file saved in web server folder .

In the click event of one button , I want to insert in to the excel file with datatbale details and save it as in the same folder with different name (Eg with invoicenumber).So Whenever I select new invoice number and click the button should update the excel template and save as it in the folder

I have done like this :

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string invoicenumber =textbox1.text;
        string saveasfilename = "Bulkexcel" + invoicenumber +  ".xlsx";

              string connStr = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='App_Data/exceltemplate.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        OleDbConnection MyConnection;
        OleDbCommand MyCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        MyConnection.Open();
        MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
        string sql = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (id,name) values('3','c')";
        MyCommand.CommandText = sql;
        MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MyConnection.Close();

                   'App_Data/exceltemplate.xls'.SaveAs(MapPath("App_Data/" +  saveasfilename ))


        Label1.Text = "data inserted successfully !! ";


    }
```

I am able to insert the data in to excel-template but not able to save it as with the name I am giving during the run time in the server folder .

Please help me.

Comment: what is  'App_Data/exceltemplate.xls'.SaveAs(MapPath("App_Data/" +  saveasfilename )) ;It shows me an error?

Comment: It is the exceltemplatefile saved in App_Data folder .once the data inserted in to this file , it should save as with the name given during the run time in the same folder

Comment: Actually you should copy the template first and insert then into the copied template. Otherwise you're going to modify your template.

Comment: How can I copy the template and save it as in the same folder